# Is there a nutch schema.xml that works with solr 5.3.1 in basic config (single core)?

Tags: solr, nutch

Trying to integrate Nutch 4.10.1 with Solr 5.3.1 as in the Nutch Tutorial to index a crawl.

- A similar questions asked on 4/9, but no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use schema-4.xml found under nutch's conf folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I got it to work with the following ...

1. I copied schema-solr4.xml from notch conf folder to the solar 5.3.1 conf folder.
2. Copied the sole schema.xml to schema (copy).xml
3. Renamed schema-solr4.xml to schema.xml (in the Solr core folder)
4. Ran the  command in a  terminal window

   - then ran  -d sample_techproducts_configs 
     Received an error message "ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore : Unable to create core [core] Caused by: enablePositionIncrements is not a valid option as of Lucene 5.0"
5. Revised schema.xml to delete all " enablePositionIncrements="true"
6. Reran  -d sample_techproducts_configs 
   Receive an ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'core': Unable to create core [core] Caused by: copyField dest :'location' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField.
7. Revised schema.xml to delete ""
8. Reran  -d sample_techproducts_configs

   It worked - create the core.
9. Was able to index from nutch 1.10 to this core in solr 5.3.1 (using bin/nutch solrindex ...)

*It may be necessary to restart solr before creating core.

Comment: In Step 7 - it should have read  "<copyField source="latLon" dest="location"/>" rather than "".